# Adding background image in css with get_option() in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am building simple scroller and admin should paste the link to the image in the admin panel and that image should output as a background of slide div. I have set up the options for this, and links are being saved to the database I just don't know how to add it to the style rules.

I have included the following code to the `<head></head>`

```
<style type="text/css">
<![CDATA[]]>
#slide_1 {
background-image: url('<?php echo get_option('slide_1'); ?>');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
]]></style>
```

In firebug the url is being displayed in the `<head></head>` but the style is not applied, and `#slide_1` doesn't have any rules applied to it.

Is there any other way of doing this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Try removing the [CDATA]. If your page is getting parsed as HTML instead of XHTML it probably won't recognize the styles.

Comment: I posted that as an answer with references so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `[CDATA]`. If your page is getting parsed as HTML instead of XHTML it probably won't recongize the styles.

For further reading, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) states:

> CDATA sections in XHTML documents are liable to be parsed differently
>   by web browsers if they render the document as HTML, since HTML
>   parsers do not recognise the CDATA start and end markers, nor do they
>   recognise HTML entity references such as < within  tags.

Answer (score 1):

May be there is a CSS background rule is being applied forcefully. You can try using inline style. Like.

```
<div id="slide_1" style="background: url('<?php echo get_option("slide_1");?>') no-repeat;">
.....
</div>
```

**Another thing I have noticed** that in css rule `background-image: url('<?php echo get_option('slide_1'); ?>');` you are using single quotes in php and also in css. This is producing a conflict. Try using `background-image: url('<?php echo get_option("slide_1"); ?>');` double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

just removed `<![CDATA[]]>` and works fine